# Single Sign on between Joomla and Wordpress

Tags: joomla

I have a wordpress instance installed in joomla's root folder, I would like to enable Single Sign On with joomla and wordpress. How do i do that. Also, i tried with attempting to access session value set in joomla page in my wordpress. But an not able to access it.

Appreciate any methods to enable Single Sign on bt/w joomla and wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jfusion would probably be the easiest way to handle the dual login.

http://www.jfusion.org/

Comment: i istalled Jfusion.....But it does not provide me a plugin to integrate Joomla with wordpress......it does provide u a document though...........

Comment: I understand that a WP plugin is due shortly and that you can also use the universal plugin.

Comment: Can i use universal plugin untill WP plugin is released....? wer can i get universal plugin

Comment: I have not done it myself with WP, but there are bunches of Google results on the subject. The universal plugin should come with the full install package - http://www.jfusion.org/downloads/category/1-latest_release