# login to joomla from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla

I have joomla site in which there is one blog section which is the integration of wordpress(Wp is subdomain of joomla site).

On the joomla site there is one login component.while i am in the blog section i have given a funcionality of login to the user but as its blog section of wordpress and login functionality belongs to joomla so i want any way to check the credentials against the joomla from the blog(Wp) section.

How to accomplish this? any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358534/single-sign-on-between-joomla-and-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible as both CMS's use different methods for logging a user in.

For passwords, Joomla use md5 and salt methods. Wordpress on the other hand use a [Portable PHP Password Hashing Framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/). Also, the API's are completely different.

I'm not sure if you're site is purely for a blog, that you didn't just stick to Wordpress rather than integrating a Wordpress blog into Joomla. No the best idea :/

Answer (score 0):

I would look on the [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) for [Authentication Bridges](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-bridges/) (like [JFusion](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-bridges/3723) which has WordPress support amongst many others), or taking a different approach, in the [Blog Integration section](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog-integration/6659) e.g. [WordPress Blog for Joomla](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog-integration/6659)